# How to fix this 'Invalid Region <center:-180.00000000, -180.00000000 span:nan, nan>' error in swift

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkcoordinateregion

I would like to get the region so I can fit the annotations inside of it. But I got uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region '. So how cloud I resolve this problem please ?

```
var topLeftCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -90, longitude: 180)
var bottomRightCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 90, longitude: -180)

for annotation in mapView.annotations where !annotation.isKind(of: DriverAnnotation.self){
            topLeftCoordinate.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoordinate.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude)
            topLeftCoordinate.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude)
            bottomRightCoordinate.longitude = fmin(bottomRightCoordinate.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude)
            bottomRightCoordinate.latitude = fmax(bottomRightCoordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude)
        }
```

> var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center:
>   CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(topLeftCoordinate.latitude -
>   (topLeftCoordinate.latitude - bottomRightCoordinate.latitude) * 0.5,
>   topLeftCoordinate.longitude + (bottomRightCoordinate.longitude -
>   topLeftCoordinate.longitude) * 0.5), span:
>   MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: fabs(topLeftCoordinate.latitude -
>   bottomRightCoordinate.latitude) * 2.0, longitudeDelta:
>   fabs(bottomRightCoordinate.longitude - topLeftCoordinate.longitude) *
>   2.0))
>
> region = mapView.regionThatFits(region)  mapView.setRegion(region,
>   animated: true)

Comment: Your coords are backwards. Top left should be `90, -180` and bottom right should be `-90, 180`.

Comment: @rmaddy I just tried your solution but it give me the same error back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong way to calculate the rectangle which fits the bounds of all annotations.

Use this, it maps the annotations to their coordinates and then to `MKMapRect` instances. The `reduce/union` function calculates the size of the rect

```
let coordinates = mapView.annotations.lazy.filter{!($0 is DriverAnnotation)}.map{ $0.coordinate }
let rects = coordinates.map { MKMapRect(origin: MKMapPoint($0), size: MKMapSize()) }
let mapRect = rects.reduce(MKMapRect.null) { $0.union($1) }
mapView.setVisibleMapRect(mapRect, animated: true)
```

Or, much simpler (thanks to Sulthan)

```
let annotations = mapView.annotations.filter{!($0 is DriverAnnotation)}
mapView.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: true)
```

Comment: Yes, I just added the code to filter the `DriverAnnotation` instances.

Comment: It's working but the how cloud I adjust the zoom so the two annotations cloud be visible on the screen ?

Comment: I have no idea which *two annotations* you mean. The code is supposed to show all filtered annotations.

Comment: I had to show the Passenger Annotation and the MKPointAnnotation instead of the driver one. That's why the one of the driver is not !annotation.isKind(of: DriverAnnotation.self)

Comment: My edited code considers only annotations which are not `DriverAnnotation`

Comment: Isn't this what [showAnnotations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452309-showannotations) do?